# PHP Datetime Object with earlier datetime has higher timestamp value?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to do a function that will return true if now is currently between certain hours and days of the week.

Thing is, the unix timestamps don't seem to match.

```
<?php
function isWorkingTime() {
  $now = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:00'), new DateTimeZone(date('T')));

  $tz = $now->getTimezone();
  if(strtolower($tz->getName()) != 'est'){
    $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('EST'));
  }

  $min = clone $now;
  $min->setTime(8,30,0);

  $max = clone $now;
  switch($now->format('N')){
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      $max->setTime(17,30,0);
      break;
    case 5:
      $max->setTime(16,30,0);
      break;
    default:
      return false;
      break;
  }

  return ($now >= $min && $now < $max);
}
?>
```

If I go on and try to output the 3 datetime objects, like so:

```
<?php
echo 'now: '.$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s U T').PHP_EOL;
echo 'min: '.$min->format('Y-m-d H:i:s U T').PHP_EOL;
echo 'max: '.$max->format('Y-m-d H:i:s U T').PHP_EOL;
?>
```

I get this:

```
now: 2017-02-15 13:17:00 1487164620 EST
min: 2017-02-15 08:30:00 1487165400 EST
max: 2017-02-15 17:30:00 1487197800 EST
```

Why's $min timestamp bigger than $now?

I'm running PHP 5.6.30

Comment: Are you sure on this? The first timestamp listed `1487164620` is `2017-02-15 13:17:00` - but in UTC Time. So, would be 07:30 in EST, which then is actually smaller than `min`. I cannot reproduce this, your code is working as expected.

Comment: @dognose I reproduced it https://3v4l.org/YtC7u

Comment: funny thing I can't reproduce it for php 5.6.30: https://3v4l.org/VDETE

Comment: You're trying to compare objects arithmetically ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Docu states that you should not use EST, with a warning about "strange" effects:

> Warning Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides
>   UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons, and may expose
>   erroneous behavior.

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Running your snippet with a proper Timezone Name like `America/New_York` does not show this issue: https://3v4l.org/NR3cg

to be clear about the issue / error:

Using EST: 
https://3v4l.org/BdUan

```
02/15/2017 6:00 am 1487138400 -> TS says 02/15/2017 @ 6:00am (UTC) (wrong)
02/15/2017 8:30 am 1487165400 -> TS says 02/15/2017 @ 1:30pm (UTC) (right)
```

Using America/New_York:
https://3v4l.org/ndISv

```
02/15/2017 6:00 am 1487156400 -> TS says 02/15/2017 @ 11:00am (UTC) (right)
02/15/2017 8:30 am 1487165400 -> TS says 02/15/2017 @ 1:30pm (UTC) (right)
```

(while everything should be the verysame timestamp, compare with line 2)

Comment: I think you are correct indeed! Using Canada/Eastern actually makes it work. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobS  5.4.16 works as well with EST. I can't find the changelogs, but I remember, that the removal of certain timezone abbreviations was listed somewhere... So, I believe that for later versions a "fraction" of the code still can handle EST, while other parts can't anymore, leading to this strange behaviour.

Comment: @pycvalade But `Canada/Eastern` is listed on the DO NOT USE Page as well... So you better find something else i'd say, for example `America/Toronto` :P

Answer (score 0):

settimezone does not change the underlying timestamp, only the display format for the timestamp.

The result is, you created a datetime in GMT. That means the timestamp is from GMT. Then you changed the timezone so that it displays the time in EST, but the actual time is still from GMT.

Then you create a NEW datetime in EST and set the time *in EST*. The actual underlying time/timestamp is from EST. You then duplicated this process.

The result is that you have UTC timestamps created from one GMT time (now), and two EST times (min/max).

Edit:
The takeaway is that DateTime::setTimeZone only affects how the time is displayed visually. It does not change the point in time it is in reference to when it was created.

Second Edit:
I cannot replicate the problem. This may be a bug in the version of PHP you are running, but format('U') should give the correct unix timestamp for the formatted time you are using. It is clearly not, because your timestamp for now matches what it would be in GMT rather than EST.

Comment: Thought about that first as well - but a unix-timestamp is "unix time". It doesn't care about the timezone. setTimeZone ofc. does not change the Point in time - because it IS the same point in time everywhere.

Comment: It doesn't change the point in time. 8:30 -0600 comes after 13:10 -0000 every day of every week. Edit: In case you're having trouble with that. 8:30 -0600 is 14:30 GMT. 13:10 GMT is before 14:30 GMT.

Comment: Please see the edit on my answer to make the actual problem "clear". Both results should be equal, only the case using EST yields a wrong result. (It displays the correct time, but handles the timestamp as if that time would be UTC time)

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but in your case it seems you need to set timezone again after setTime():

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:00'), new DateTimeZone(date('T')));
echo '          original: '.$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s U T').PHP_EOL;
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('EST'));
echo '    after timezone: '.$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s U T').PHP_EOL;
$now->setTime(8,30,0);
echo '     after settime: '.$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s U T').PHP_EOL;
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('EST'));
echo 'after 2nd timezone: '.$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s U T').PHP_EOL;
```

result:

```
          original: 2017-02-15 22:44:00 1487187840 MSK
    after timezone: 2017-02-15 14:44:00 1487169840 EST
     after settime: 2017-02-15 08:30:00 1487165400 EST
after 2nd timezone: 2017-02-15 08:30:00 1487147400 EST
```

> suggestion note: `$now->format('U')` gives you wrong timestamp, for actual timestamp you need to retrieve it via `$now->getTimestamp()` it must be equal original timestamp.

Comment: For reference, ->getTimestamp will always give the original timestamp the DateTime was created with, or for the last time that was set. It won't reflect timezone changes properly. format should (or is "supposed to") give the correct timestamp for the displayed time.

Comment: imo, it's slightly wrong way... timestamp needs to be the same every time for every timezone, but timezone-settings will affect on format.. but nvm, it's only my imo

Comment: @Wizard Agree, timestamp should never ever change, no matter what timezone you set. (Timestamps are UTC by design)